# LDAPS connection through PHP on IIS

Tags: php, ssl, iis

Trying to sort out an LDAPs connection over windows / PHP:

I have `.pfx` certificate available to me and an LDAP(s) configuration requirement running on Windows 2012R2 / IIS 8.5. I currently have a folder structure: `C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf` and within here is my `LDAP.Conf` file with an entry:

```
TLS_CACERT c:\openldap\sysconf\XXX.pfx
```

The `pfx` file is encrypted so I am assuming I need to 'install' the certificate on the IIS server.

I have the required password for the chain but I'm a little fuzzy on exactly where / process for installing the certificate on the IIS Server for this particular requirement.

Can anyone explain / guide me as to how to complete this side of it ?

Very Very appreciated in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can import/install the pfx (private key & certificate archive) for the ActiveDirectory services using Microsoft management console.

> You need to launch MMC then import the certificate by selecting
>   File->Add or remove snap-in->select Certificates->click add(to add it
>   to the selected snap-ins)->click ok->select service account , then
>   selecting local computer then selecting active directory
>   service->finish.

This site will guide you through your configuration:
A complete and step by step info is given

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-active-directory-ldap-2012.htm

You can verify your Ldap configuration by importing the public certificate to your personal certificate store through MMC or by just double clicking it and following the wizard then use ldp tool to verify the SSL connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Ram, just in case anyone else views this:

After obtaining the certificate, converted it to a .pem file using:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Comment: Thanks Ram, just in case anyone else views this:

After obtaining the certificate, converted it to a .pem file using:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Create a file within C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf called ldap.conf and place the following line entries within it:

TLS_REQCERT never
TLS_CACERT c:\openldap\sysconf\Certificate.pem

This seems to have done the trick